# How to set placeholder in input type date [React]

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to know how to set placeholder in input date.

this is my code

```
<input type="text" onChange={(e) => { setbirth(moment(e.target.value).format('YYYYMMDD')) }} placeholder="생년월일" onFocus="(this.type = 'date')" onBlur="(this.type='text')" />
```

I've looked through the question, but using this code
throws an error.

```
onfocus="(this.type='date')" onblur="(this.type='text')"


Warning: Expected `onFocus` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
Warning: Expected `onBlur` listener to be a function, instead got a value of `string` type.
```

Is there any way to change it without error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
import React , { useRef } from "react";

const App= () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="date"
        ref={ref}
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => (ref.current.type = "date")}
        onBlur={() => (ref.current.type = "date")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default  App
```

Answer (score 8):

`useRef` is not recommended here as it doesn't helps in re-rendering the component and hence it will not change the `type` of input. The better approach is to initialize it as type "text" and change the types based on the events on `onFocus` and `onBlur`. For your use case, please go through the code below.

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={(e) => (e.target.type = "date")}
        onBlur={(e) => (e.target.type = "text")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The error is because onFocus and onBlur are event emitters that expect to fire a callback. In your code, `onFocus` and `onBlur` is a statement instead of a callback and thus the error.

You can use react `RefObject` to do it easily.
Reference:

- https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/focus_event
- https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/blur_event

```
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={ref}
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => (ref.current.type = "date")}
        onBlur={() => (ref.current.type = "text")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit exciting-stonebraker-jq0f4]

Answer (score 0):

```
import React , { useRef, useState } from "react";

const App= () => {
  const ref = useRef();
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        ref={ref}
        placeholder="Date"
        onChange={({target}) => setValue(target?.value)}
        onFocus={() => {
           if(ref.current){
             ref.current.type = "date"
           }
        }}
        onBlur={() => {
           if(ref.current){
             ref.current.type = value ? "date" : "text"
           }
        }}
        value={value}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
export default  App
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
import { useRef } from "react";

export default function App() {
  const ref = useRef();
  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="date"
        ref={ref}
        onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)}
        onFocus={() => (ref.current.type = "date")}
        onBlur={() => (ref.current.type = "date")}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```